# comparison of strings throws NullPointerException

Tags: java, arrays, string, comparison, nullpointerexception

I have an array of `Strings` called `letters`. When I try to execute the following line of code, I get a `NullPointerException`.

```
if(letters[j].equals(tmpst))
```

Where `j` is an arbitrary index less than the length of `letters`

`tmpst` is a string that is defined as such:

```
char myChar = theWord.charAt(i);
String tmpst = String.valueOf(myChar);
```

where `theWord` is an arbitrary string with length greater than 4.

The full code is:

```
for (int i = 0; i < theWord.length(); i++) { 
        for (int j = 0; j < letters.length; j++) { 

            char myChar = theWord.charAt(i);
            String tmpst = String.valueOf(myChar);

            if(letters[j].equals(tmpst)) { 
                System.out.println("YOU DIDIT!!! :D");
                newWord = newWord + theWord.charAt(i);
            }

        }
```

Can someone see what I'm doing wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: Provide the full code, of the values i and j are taking.

Comment: There has to be something wrong with the index `j`. Provide the full code

Comment: Array `letters` might not been *initialized*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It seems that your array contains some null references. You can use `Arrays.toString(letters)` to see if it is true.

If you want that your comparisson still works even if your array contains null values, you should change your code to be like this:

```
if(tmpst.equals(letters[j]))
```

Comment: The `letters` array is supposed to carry some null values, but I didn't think that would be a problem, because null is equal to a string

Comment: @Jeeter Null is not equals to a empty string. if tou want to make it work this way you should invert the parameters, doing the verification this way: if(tmpst.equals(letters[j])). I will add it to the answer.

Comment: In Java, null is never "equal" to anything other than null.  Note particularly that "" and null are not equal.  "" is an object, null is the absence of an object.

Comment: Your latest answer worked for me. Thank you for your help! :)

Answer (score 0):

If the expression `letters.length` evaluated without problems, then `letters[j]` is null, this is the only possibility. You can't call methods on null references.

You should write something considering the case if it is null like this:

```
if (letters[j] != null && letters[j].equals(tmpst)) {
```

Answer (score 0):

You Need to understand the difference.
For instance , There is a `String myString`.Now `myString == null` and myString.equals("") are two different things.
Before using `myString.equals("")` , you must need to assure that your string is initialized and not null. So ,your this error is coming because of non intialization of your string object at any index.
 Try to check it by using `myString == null`
Feel free to ask if you  have any embiguity :)

Answer (score 0):

check for `!=null` first, then use `.equals()` method.....
because `null` is not a string.so can't user `.equals()` method